# How to unfocus the InputNumber antd element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, antd

I am having this issue with the code that when I try to change the value of InputNumber using onchange event, the focus gets shifted to First InputNumber element and not where I desire to change. So this leads to scrolling of the page on every change of InputNumber
Here is my minimal piece of code:
[Minimal Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-chaum-lmvp9)

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create refs of these inputs at your parent component and then use the focus function whenever a change occurs.

```
class DemoComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef1 = React.createRef();
    this.inputRef2 = React.createRef();
  }

  getInputNumber = (e, para, inputRef) => {
    console.log(e, para);
    storeInputNumber[e] = para;
    inputRef.focus();
  };
```

and

```
      <InputNumber
        id="input 2"
        ref={input => {
          this.inputRef1 = input;
        }}
        onChange={e => {
          this.getInputNumber(e, "input 2", this.inputRef1);
        }}
      />
```

same is for the other input.

Check my codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-newton-918jn

Comment: yes your solution works thanks. But can you please let me know why my solution doesnt works, as it is simple basic antd. The issue arises even when there is no onChange method